# i have bad shading in my mesh how to fix it?

Tags: shaders, subdivision-surface

I am modeling a robot head and i nearly complete it and when I applied **subdivision modifier** i had this problen -also I apply *shade smooth* and *auto smooth* and *recalculate teh normal* - :

[image: the problem]

Is this shading problem and how to fix it, **and thanks in advance**.

This the blend. file: [blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pQ9wnjBAfZuZnTF6bvP1Y3K0Tap3vCzW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is probably a topology problem (can you show us the wireframe, or the mesh in Edit mode ?). I suggest you read this : https://topologyguides.com/page-3/ (the whole site ; it's only 3 pages. Beware, articles are in reverse order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use inset (I) then scale (S) to add additional loopcuts...so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks it works

Comment: you are welcome!